# properties of complex number multiplication

Tags: complex-numbers

Could you please explain to me why this simple equation is true

$$-i * i = 1$$

or

$$-\sqrt{1}*\sqrt{1}=1$$

I know basic properties of roots $$\sqrt{a} * \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a*b}$$

but what I get is $$-\sqrt{-1} * \sqrt{-1} = -\sqrt{(-1)*(-1)}= -\sqrt{1} = -1$$

Comment: In complex numbers, you either have to take $\sqrt{x}$ as a multi-valued function, or you have to abandon $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equality $-i\cdot i=1$ is equivalent to $i\cdot i=-1$.

But $i^2=-1$ is a property of $i$, so you're done.

$\sqrt{-1}$ is not one number, but two numbers:
$\sqrt{-1}=a\iff a^2=-1$, there are two such $a$: $a=i$ and $a=-i$.

Answer (score 1):

Another idea worth keeping in mind is that the property $\sqrt{a}*\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ only holds when $a,b\ge0$. This explains why you were obtaining $-1$ when trying to apply the property.

Answer (score 0):

1) $-i*i = -i^2 = -(-1) = 1$.

2)$-\sqrt 1 * \sqrt 1 = -(1)*1 = -1 \ne 1$.

3) $\sqrt{a}*\sqrt{b} = \sqrt{a*b}$. This isn't true.  The is only true for non-negative real numbers.  What is true is $\sqrt{|a|}*\sqrt{|b|} = \sqrt{|ab|}$.  For real numbers we just never take square roots of negative numbers so this distinction is usually unnecessary.

I need to also point out the very notion of $\sqrt{a}$ is a convenience.  If $a \ne 0$ then there are *two* solutions to $x^2 =a$.  The term $\sqrt{a}$ is only *one* of them.  If $a >0$ the convention is that $\sqrt{a}$ *specifically* refers *only* to the positive one.  There is no such agreed upon convention for complex numbers.  If we use the notation $\sqrt{}$ in a complex context it's usually (but not always) understood to have two possible values.

4) $-\sqrt{-1} *\sqrt{-1} = -\sqrt{-1*-1} = -\sqrt{1} = - 1$.

This is a well known "false proof".  It doesn't work because i)$\sqrt{-1}$ is ambiguous and ii) $\sqrt{-1} *\sqrt{-1} \ne \sqrt{-1*-1}$